# On button focus, why am I getting two different border radii?

Tags: html, css, focus, accessibility

I set up a `focus-visible` state on a button. The button has a border radius of 4px, and the focus state adds a box-shadow with a border-radius attached to that as well. However, when I tab to the button, the radius on the outer border is not 4px. How can I get those outer border corners to a radius of 4px, like the button is?

***These buttons are only keyboard navigable. Clicking on them won't provide the focus state.**

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap");
/*resets*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn--small {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
.btn--medium {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
.btn--large {
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
}
.btn--standard {
  background: #005FEC;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn:focus-visible {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #ffffff, 0 0 0 8px #005FEC;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn--small btn--standard">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn--medium btn--standard">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn--large btn--standard">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you checking it in? Safari and IE do not yet support focus-visible and I can see it work well on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/xxdwbRV).

Comment: First of all, IE loses support completely in most browsers in less than a year. With Safari, I can add a fallback. You may have to zoom in to see it, but the outer corner has a much wider radius than the button itself. See [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/183wdd8). Also, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: You need to style the :focus pseudo as well as the class as it's a default browser style.